# Movie where child-sized, mushrooms-eating aliens are us from the future

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens

I am looking for the title of a movie I saw on the Sci-Fi channel years ago.

The plot is that a military man at the beginning asks his commanding officer about why UFOs are downplayed and is told it is because of the panic it could cause. For some reason, he helps the child-like alien escape and shaves his head bald. The alien eats mushrooms and when they finally get to the ship, the soldier finds out that the ship is actually from Earth's future and the "alien" is what we will evolve into. Because the environment is so different, the alien dies.

Later when the CO asks if the soldier will tell anyone he responds with:

> What am I going to tell them? That we will evolve into child-sized greys that eat mushrooms?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a bit of a long shot, but could this be ["Official Denial"](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0110715/)?

I frankly do not remember all that much from the movie, but some parts overlap with what you describe:

> The plot is that a military man at the beginning asks his CO about why UFOs are downplayed and is told it is because of the panic it could cause.

Not sure about this one. But the military *is* involved; they capture a crashed UFO and hold one of the aliens (the only surviving crewmember?) captive. They want the protagonist to communicate with it.

> For some reason he helps the child like alien

While the alien is smaller than the average human, it turns out to be an adult future human woman.

> escape and shaves his head bald.

Can't quite remember that, but the movie poster seems to suggest it.

> The alien eats mushrooms and when they finally get to the ship the soldier finds out that the ship is actually from Earths future and the "alien" is what we will evolve into. Because the environment is so different the alien dies.

I don't remember her dying, either, but she does report about future Earth's largely destroyed environment (which she may have adapted to in some way, though).

Answer (score 10):

*Official Denial* (1993), Syfy's first original film.

From [IMDb](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0110715/):

> A man who claims to have been abducted by aliens is also abducted by a top secret government agency, the Majestic Group, who want him to attempt to communicate with the only surviving alien from a UFO shot down by the Air Force. Telepathically, the alien tells him it must be returned to its ship, where it will reveal a secret vital to the future of the planet.

It's on YouTube and the bit you remember is at 1:23:04:

> LT. COL. DAN LERNER: You, uh, still think we should tell everyone?
>
> PAUL CORLISS: *(scoffs)* What would we tell them? That they're gonna evolve into something little, and grey, that eats mushrooms?

---

Found in the "Film" section of the ["Transhuman Aliens" TVTropes page](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TranshumanAliens), which I found with the Google query `tvtropes aliens are future humans`. [Hat tip to @F1Krazy for this tip!](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/12293/98028)